# running spark job on local cluster runs infinitely

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, spark-submit

I have setup a local spark cluster on my windows 7 machine ( a master and worker node). I have created a simple scala script which i build with sbt and try to run with spark-submit. Please find the resources below

Scala code :

```
package example1

import java.io._

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext 
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object HelloWorld {

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("===============================================")
        println("===============================================") 
        println("Hello, world!")
        val pw = new PrintWriter(new File("d:\\hello.txt" ))
        pw.write("Hello, world")

        println("===============================================")
        println("===============================================")

        val session = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()


        var filesmall = "file:///D:/_Work/azurepoc/samplebigdata/ds2.csv"

        //val df  =  session.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(filesmall)

        println("===============================================")

        pw.write("Hello, world some more information ")
        pw.close
    }
}
```

Spark cluster Master script :

```
C:\Windows\system32>spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master
2019-01-03 16:49:16 INFO  Master:2612 - Started daemon with process name: 23940@ws-amalhotra
2019-01-03 16:49:16 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2019-01-03 16:49:16 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: admin
2019-01-03 16:49:16 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: admin
2019-01-03 16:49:16 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-01-03 16:49:16 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-01-03 16:49:16 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(admin); groups with view permissions: Set(); user
s  with modify permissions: Set(admin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'sparkMaster' on port 7077.
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Master:54 - Starting Spark master at spark://192.168.8.101:7077
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Master:54 - Running Spark version 2.3.2
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  log:192 - Logging initialized @1412ms
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Server:351 - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: unknown, git hash: unknown
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Server:419 - Started @1489ms
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  AbstractConnector:278 - Started ServerConnector@16391414{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'MasterUI' on port 8080.
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@204e3825{/app,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@748394e8{/app/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@19b99890{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5c0f561c{/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3443bda1{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@54541f46{/app/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6e8c3d12{/driver/kill,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  MasterWebUI:54 - Bound MasterWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://ws-amalhotra.domain.co.in:8080
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Server:351 - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: unknown, git hash: unknown
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@22eb9260{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  AbstractConnector:278 - Started ServerConnector@636eb125{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{192.168.8.101:6066}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Server:419 - Started @1558ms
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service on port 6066.
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  StandaloneRestServer:54 - Started REST server for submitting applications on port 6066
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1a4c3e84{/metrics/master/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5a3b4746{/metrics/applications/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:17 INFO  Master:54 - I have been elected leader! New state: ALIVE
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Master:54 - Registering worker 192.168.8.101:8089 with 8 cores, 14.9 GB RAM
```

My Worker node :

```
C:\Windows\system32>spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.8.101:7077 -p 8089
2019-01-03 16:49:20 INFO  Worker:2612 - Started daemon with process name: 16264@ws-amalhotra
2019-01-03 16:49:21 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: admin
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: admin
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(admin); groups with view permissions: Set(); user
s  with modify permissions: Set(admin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 8089.
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Worker:54 - Starting Spark worker 192.168.8.101:8089 with 8 cores, 14.9 GB RAM
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Worker:54 - Running Spark version 2.3.2
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Worker:54 - Spark home: C:\spark
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  log:192 - Logging initialized @1471ms
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Server:351 - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: unknown, git hash: unknown
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Server:419 - Started @1518ms
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  AbstractConnector:278 - Started ServerConnector@44629c8f{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@36f34cce{/logPage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@447fb46{/logPage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3b027ba{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5396b0bb{/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@6830ec44{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5eb28ff8{/log,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  WorkerWebUI:54 - Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://ws-amalhotra.domain.co.in:8081
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Worker:54 - Connecting to master 192.168.8.101:7077...
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@36cc352{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to /192.168.8.101:7077 after 26 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2019-01-03 16:49:21 INFO  Worker:54 - Successfully registered with master spark://192.168.8.101:7077
```

Now I build and package the scala code with sbt that packages it into a JAR. My build.sbt file looks like below

```
version := "1.0" 
scalaVersion := "2.11.8" 
val sparkVersion = "2.0.0" 

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( 
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion, 
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % sparkVersion, 
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion 
    )
```

It creates a jar and I submit it using the spark submit command as below :

```
C:\Users\amalhotra>spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://192.168.
8.101:6066 --class "example1.HelloWorld"  "D:\_Work\azurepoc\sbtexample\target\s
cala-2.11\sbtexample_2.11-1.0.jar"
```

**Everything works fine and now i just change a single line of code in my script and again follow the compile -> sbt package code -> spark-submit (same as above). The code change is I uncomment the below line :**

```
 //val df  =  session.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(filesmall)
```

**When I again run the above with spark-submit, the worker executes forever. Also , the file in my D drive is not getting written. Worker logs below**

```
C:\Windows\system32>spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker spark://192.168.8.101:7077 -p 8089
2019-01-03 17:24:38 INFO  Worker:2612 - Started daemon with process name: 24952@ws-amalhotra
2019-01-03 17:24:39 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(admin); groups with view permissions: Set(); user
s  with modify permissions: Set(admin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'sparkWorker' on port 8089.
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  Worker:54 - Starting Spark worker 192.168.8.101:8089 with 8 cores, 14.9 GB RAM
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  Worker:54 - Running Spark version 2.3.2
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  Worker:54 - Spark home: C:\spark
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  log:192 - Logging initialized @1512ms
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  Server:351 - jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT, build timestamp: unknown, git hash: unknown
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  Server:419 - Started @1561ms
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  AbstractConnector:278 - Started ServerConnector@51e2ccae{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  Utils:54 - Successfully started service 'WorkerUI' on port 8081.
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3d96670b{/logPage,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@48e02860{/logPage/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@758918a3{/,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1643bea5{/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5f293725{/static,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@339a8612{/log,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  WorkerWebUI:54 - Bound WorkerWebUI to 0.0.0.0, and started at http://ws-amalhotra.domain.co.in:8081
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  Worker:54 - Connecting to master 192.168.8.101:7077...
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  ContextHandler:781 - Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@196e9c2a{/metrics/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
2019-01-03 17:24:39 INFO  TransportClientFactory:267 - Successfully created connection to /192.168.8.101:7077 after 29 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
2019-01-03 17:24:40 INFO  Worker:54 - Successfully registered with master spark://192.168.8.101:7077
2019-01-03 17:25:17 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch driver driver-20190103172517-0000
2019-01-03 17:25:17 INFO  DriverRunner:54 - Copying user jar file:/D:/_Work/azurepoc/sbtexample/target/scala-2.11/sbtexample_2.11-1.0.jar to C:\spark\work\driver-20190103172517-0000\sbtexamp
le_2.11-1.0.jar
2019-01-03 17:25:17 INFO  Utils:54 - Copying D:\_Work\azurepoc\sbtexample\target\scala-2.11\sbtexample_2.11-1.0.jar to C:\spark\work\driver-20190103172517-0000\sbtexample_2.11-1.0.jar
2019-01-03 17:25:17 INFO  DriverRunner:54 - Launch Command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\spark\jars\*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.master=spark://19
2.168.8.101:7077" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=false" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.jars=file:/D:/_Work/azurepoc/sbtexample/target/scala-2.11/sbtexample_2.11-1.0.jar" "-Dspark.ap
p.name=example1.HelloWorld" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.101:8089" "C:\spark\work\driver-20190103172517-0000\sbtexample_2.11-1.0.jar" "example1.He
lloWorld"
2019-01-03 17:25:19 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20190103172519-0000/0 for example1.HelloWorld
2019-01-03 17:25:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:25:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:25:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:25:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:25:19 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(admin); groups with view permissions: Set(); user
s  with modify permissions: Set(admin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-01-03 17:25:19 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\spark\jars\*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=557
86" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws-amalhotra.domain.co.in:55786" "--executor-id" "0" "--hostname" "192.168.8.101" "--
cores" "7" "--app-id" "app-20190103172519-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.101:8089"
2019-01-03 17:25:43 INFO  Worker:54 - Executor app-20190103172519-0000/0 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
2019-01-03 17:25:43 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20190103172519-0000/1 for example1.HelloWorld
2019-01-03 17:25:43 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:25:43 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:25:43 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:25:43 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:25:43 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(admin); groups with view permissions: Set(); user
s  with modify permissions: Set(admin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-01-03 17:25:43 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\spark\jars\*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=557
86" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws-amalhotra.domain.co.in:55786" "--executor-id" "1" "--hostname" "192.168.8.101" "--
cores" "7" "--app-id" "app-20190103172519-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.101:8089"
2019-01-03 17:26:05 INFO  Worker:54 - Executor app-20190103172519-0000/1 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
2019-01-03 17:26:05 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20190103172519-0000/2 for example1.HelloWorld
2019-01-03 17:26:05 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:26:05 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:26:05 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:26:05 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:26:05 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(admin); groups with view permissions: Set(); user
s  with modify permissions: Set(admin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-01-03 17:26:05 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\spark\jars\*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=557
86" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws-amalhotra.domain.co.in:55786" "--executor-id" "2" "--hostname" "192.168.8.101" "--
cores" "7" "--app-id" "app-20190103172519-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.101:8089"
2019-01-03 17:26:28 INFO  Worker:54 - Executor app-20190103172519-0000/2 finished with state EXITED message Command exited with code 1 exitStatus 1
2019-01-03 17:26:28 INFO  Worker:54 - Asked to launch executor app-20190103172519-0000/3 for example1.HelloWorld
2019-01-03 17:26:28 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:26:28 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls to: admin
2019-01-03 17:26:28 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing view acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:26:28 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - Changing modify acls groups to:
2019-01-03 17:26:28 INFO  SecurityManager:54 - SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(admin); groups with view permissions: Set(); user
s  with modify permissions: Set(admin); groups with modify permissions: Set()
2019-01-03 17:26:28 INFO  ExecutorRunner:54 - Launch command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\java" "-cp" "C:\spark\bin\..\conf\;C:\spark\jars\*" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.port=557
86" "org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend" "--driver-url" "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@ws-amalhotra.domain.co.in:55786" "--executor-id" "3" "--hostname" "192.168.8.101" "--
cores" "7" "--app-id" "app-20190103172519-0000" "--worker-url" "spark://Worker@192.168.8.101:8089"
```

This keeps running forever with same logs repeated every few seconds. Its unclear whats going on. The logs are not saying much. There are no full length examples which show running such jobs on a local standalone cluster

Comment: Looks like the spark application is retrying something or awaiting for some event. Is it because you have the file opened and spark is waiting for the lock to get released.

Comment: no, i have not opened the file at all

Comment: Have you tried to completely remove the usage of `PrintWriter`, and work from there?

Comment: @AlexGrigore On the contrary, when i keep only printwriter related code, it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, but you want to know if the spark part works. So first I would rule out anything that is not necessary for that, being `PrintWriter` (could have something to do with that file, how it is treated in local mode. What is the number of executors? Is it more than one?). Also, you aren't doing anything with the loaded data. At least put a `df.show()` in there.

Comment: @AlexGrigore just resolved the above issue. tried the same on my personal machine and everything worked just fine. It was a port firewall related issue.  But i really have a serious question now. You must have observed the above logs, i have done that as well... *Why is it unclear what the error is?* It should have been intuitive from just the logs that something is wrong with my firewall settings.. may be i am doing something wrong. I am not very sure.

Answer (score 0):

Set spark.driver.host in conf/spark-defaults.conf !